# windows 7 always shows me an exclamation mark

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have a Windows 7 it always shows me an exclamation mark on the shutdown button, even if there are no updates. I will shut down and restart and it goes away for a few minutes then re appears. I have checked the update history and there are no failed updates and it says there are no update available and windows is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something wrong within your Windows 7 installation.
I would give

```
sfc /scannow
```

a try from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).